# Java generics, how can I define a type that needs to be a generics with one param?

Tags: java, generics, type-systems, nested-generics

Let me give you a concrete example.

I have an interface that is called `FutureConverter`. The idea is to be able to convert `CompletableFuture` to another type. It is useful if you want to use my library in another JVM language.

I have a method that returns `CompletableFuture<MyClass>` and I want to convert the return type to `MyGenericFutureType<MyClass>`.  However, I don't know how to give `MyGenericFutureType` a parameter.

I want to be able to do something like that:

```
MyMainClass<FUTURE> {
    private final FutureConverter<FUTURE> converter;
    FUTURE<MyClass> myFunction() {
        //let's imagine soSomething is a method defined somewhere that returns CompletableFuture<MyClass>
        CompletableFuture<MyClass> myFuture = doSomething();
        return converter.convert(myFuture);
    }
}
```

Now the type param `FUTURE` doesn't know he needs a param itself so it doesn't compile obviously.

1. Is this even possible?
2. If yes, how do I do it?

I know that Java Type System can be limited, but I hope that this is possible somehow.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think, you have a design problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make it possible to adapt the API to different JVM languages, and more specifically the Future API.

Comment: Scala handles Futures differently than Java, I guess Kotlin also. I'd like to be able to plugin converters so that you can have seemless integration in those environments. The converter class will convert from CompletableFuture to another type, for example concurrent.scala.Future. But I want to be able to say that my method returns one of this future type but with the param T

Comment: So you want to have a generic converter which is able to convert to different output classes, but your `myFunction` should return the concrete type? I don't think this is possible, but you could change that to the abstract class `MyGenericFuture<T>` where `T` identifies the `MyClass` in your example.

Comment: Maybe it helps to add how you want to use the method, including concrete examples.

Comment: I would not merge the `doSomething` "business logic" with the future type conversion in the same api. Just return a static type (e.g. when you write your code in java use the java type) and provide either a stand-alone conversion facility (e.g. `WhateverFuture<T> toWhatever(CompletableFuture<T> input)`) or just copy & write the api for all the types you like to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `FutureConverter` interface as follows:

```
public interface FutureConverter<S, T> {
    MyGenericFutureType<T> convert(CompletableFuture<S> source);
}
```

In your concrete converter (from `CompletableFuture<Foo>` to `MyGenericFutureType<Foo>` you just implement `FutureConverter<Foo>`.

You might also want to have a look at Spring's converters: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.java

Comment: I think this is the best tradeoff if you want to do that but this wasn't what I was looking for.It seems that it is not possible. But I have found another way to do it. You are right my design was not compatible with Java's Type System. It works now. Thanks!